# What are some methods for supporting LaTeX formulas in Markdown?

Tags: latex, pandoc

I'm trying to convert Markdown containing LaTeX formulas, but they're not converting as expected.

I use pandoc

pandoc path/to/index.md -s -0 path/to/index.html

```markdown
$\frac{x}{2y}+\frac{x-y}{x+y}$
```

Part output html file

```html
<p><span class="math inline">$\frac{x}{2y}+\frac{x-y}{x+y}$</span></p>
```

Can anyone suggest a more suitable tool or what format should be used for the correct display of LaTeX formulas in an HTML document?

Comment: What exactly is your problem with this output, and what output are you expecting? — Have you checked out the documentation https://pandoc.org/chunkedhtml-demo/3.6-math-rendering-in-html.html?

Comment: I I expect the formula to look correct and not just the raw data that I specified

Comment: You are looking at the *source code*. The HTML source code is plain text, it doesn’t support text formatting. You should look at the rendered document *in a browser* to see the correct formula.

Comment: Maybe I didn't make myself clear, I'm sorry! But the original characters are displayed in the web browser. I think I understood how it works, the source text should be converted to svg, can you tell me how it can be done?

Comment: Did you check out the link I posted?